# TagLib tutorial

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

Are there any TagLib tutorials, how-to's, examples, etc. for Taglib with C++ (Qt)? I only found the [API Documantation](http://taglib.github.com/) with its very very basic example. But it is hard to find more examples.

Comment: Same here, I am using Qt as well and now I need a library to read audio metadata like id3 etc. I decided to go with taglib but there is only a bad documentation and very few examples on the internet. If you have found one, please don't hesitate and write your own answer to your quest :p

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the examples provided with the source code of the library. They are not Qt based, but is enough to start programming with Taglib and Qt.